# Multi-Angle, On Demand Web Video

Tags: video-streaming, html5-video, video-encoding

I am wanting to create the ability for a user to be able to playback video from multiple, synced sources.  For example, a school play filmed from different angles.  How would I enable the user to be able to select which source they would like to look at?

The possible approaches I can see are using a web player that can switch between multiple sources or some streaming server I can programatically manipulate.  I am quite keen on the server side idea.  I like the idea of using ajax to control the delivery of an HTML5 video.  Can anyone provide a different technique or some insight into how you could control the real time creation of a streaming video from different filebased sources?

Thanks in advance,
James Kent

Comment: Have you consider a slight pause while switching videos will be bad user experience. However you idea is great, and I would defiantly go with your server side idea! Good luck!

Comment: Any ideas on a technology/approaches I could use where I could change the file being streamed without dropping the stream?